# 18.04 LTS new install -- No desktop after login

Tags: 18.04, login

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 in a dual boot configuration. The installation completed without error and Ubuntu boots up to a login screen. However, when I input my password and log in, there is no gui at all except a mouse on top of a purple background (the same background as the login screen). No keyboard shortcuts work after this login either. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: which Desktop Environment you use?

Comment: Gnome, the default

Comment: did you find a answer to this

Answer (score 1):

A few of the possibilities:

- Boot into your system BIOS and disable the on-board graphics chip-set if  you have installed a discrete graphics card.
- If this does not help. Boot into Recovery mode Check file system (fsck)

If this also does not help. Boot into Recovery mode, drop to root terminal & Command:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install --reinstall lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and select lightdm

and maybe

```
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and reboot

Comment: If you haven’t reinstalled yet when at the purple screen try

Comment: Ctrl*alt+f7 follow onscreen instructions then type. startx